# Ctypes Data type conversion

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I am a ctypes beginner using Python 3.9.7 on Windows,I met a problem ,Examples are as follows

```
n = c_int(10)
print(n)
>> n = c_long(10)
```

Why does it become `c_long(10)` after it is assigned to n

Comment: Python version is 3.9.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproducible on Windows.  `c_int` is an alias for `c_long` since the size of `int` and `long` are both 32-bit on Windows.

```
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> n = c_int(10)
>>> print(n)
c_long(10)
>>> c_int
<class 'ctypes.c_long'>
>>> c_long
<class 'ctypes.c_long'>
>>> c_int is c_long       # two names for the same object
True
>>> x = int               # just like making a new name for int
>>> x
<class 'int'>
>>> int
<class 'int'>
```